# If #included, it is redefining. If not, it is not declared

Tags: c++, linker, g++

It is a quite long code, but in a nutshell, I have a main.hpp, a main.cpp, an io.hpp and an io.cpp.

Both main.cpp and io.cpp include main.hpp to use the variables declared there, and io.hpp does only include standard code:

**main.hpp**

```
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#include <somestandardstuffhere>

int counter;

#endif // MAIN_HPP
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.hpp"
#include "io.hpp"

int main(){
    doStuffWithCounter();
    return 0;
}
```

**io.hpp**

```
#ifndef IO_HPP
#define IO_HPP

#include <usedstandardstuff> // Some of the headers included here are included in main.hpp

void doStuffWithCounter();

#endif //IO_HPP
```

**io.cpp**

```
#include "main.hpp"
#include "io.hpp"

void doStuffWithCounter(){
    counter = 1;
}
```

If this is a good minimal code, when compiling you should get a linker error saying that `counter` is being redefined in its own line but, if I get rid of, for example, `io.cpp`'s `#include "main.hpp"`, the variable will not be available to use in its code.

I am compiling using only the source files: `g++ -std=c++11 io.cpp main.cpp`.

How would you fix this? Why is not `#ifndef`ing enough to prevent this errors from happening?

Comment: Not really the answer, but if you're not using the "standard" includes in the header file, you should not add them there. It will lead to them being included everywhere that header is included, showing down compilation and possibly causing namespace issues.

Comment: `int counter;` shouldn't be in the header file, since it is defining *and* declaring `counter`.  Instead, the header file should have `extern int counter;` which just declares it without defining it.

Comment: @Eljay if I do so, it tells me the variable is undeclared in `io.cpp`.

Comment: Add this to `io.cpp` near the top, after all the `#include` directives:  `int counter;`